# Localizable strings in Swift Package Manager

Tags: ios, swift, localization, swift-package-manager

I recently migrated my libraries into a `SPM`. My libraries contains also a UI stuff and pre-defines loclaized strings **e.g.:**

```
titleLabel.text = NSLoclaizedString("onboarding.page1.title", comment: "Blah blah blah")
```

I'm using a BartyCrouch for automating localization which ignores my libraries (expected). The real issue for me tho, is that when I put these in `Localizable.strings` manually, they're being ignored too

**My question is: Is there any way how to localize those?**

What I've tried, with no luck:

**Inside my Swift Package:**

```
public class LocalizableBridge {
    public static let shared = LocalizableBridge()
    public var bundle: Bundle = .main
}

final class MyViewController: UIViewController {

   // some code...

   private func setupLayout() {
        loadingLabel.text = NSLocalizedString("plugin.loading-state.title", tableName: "Localizable", bundle: LocalizableBridge.shared.bundle, value: "plugin.loading-state.title", comment: "LOADING")
        loadingLabel.textColor = .lightGray
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    }

    // some code...
}
```

Inside my project:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var appCoordinator: AppCoordinator?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        // some code...

        LocalizableBridge.shared.bundle = Bundle(identifier: "my.projects.bundle.id")!

        // some code...

        return true
    }
}
```

**Thanks guys in advance**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the strings in the wrong bundle. Try `Bundle.module` to locate them, that should be the right place.

Comment: Yes sir, that's a correct answer. Thank you. I will also add a reference to a medium article I've found: https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-add-resources-in-swift-package-manager-c437d44ec593